# How to remove code lines with ng-if or ng-class?

Tags: html, asp.net, angularjs, ng-class, angular-ng-if

How can I use ng-class or/and ng-if to get the 3 Div lines down to one line?  Each line is showing the same value but depending on what range it falls in I would like to color the text a certain color.

```
 <div class="contents">
      <div  ng-if="model.DeviceStatus.Data1 <= 24" style="color:green;">{{model.DeviceStatus.Data1}}&#8451;</div>
      <div  ng-if="model.DeviceStatus.Data1 > 24 && model.DeviceStatus.Data1 <= 35" style="color:Orange;">{{model.DeviceStatus.Data1}}&#8451;</div>
      <div  ng-if="model.DeviceStatus.Data1 > 35" style="color:red;">{{model.DeviceStatus.Data1}}&#8451;</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ng-class="{someColor: model.DeviceStatus.Data1 <= 24, anotherColor: model.DeviceStatus.Data1 > 24}"
```

You will need to creat those classes as well

```
.someColor {
  color: green; // etc
}
```

Alternatively you could use an object and ng-style

hope this helps